# how to implement @bean like Spring

Tags: java, spring

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    AuthorizeInterceptor authorizelInterceptor() {
        return new AuthorizeInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
         registry.addInterceptor(authorizelInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/user/**");
         super.addInterceptors(registry);
    }
}
```

I think `@Bean` will put the `new AuthorizeInterceptor();` into IOC and in method `addInterceptors()` call `authorizelInterceptor()` will get the bean registered in IOC. if use proxy, method `authorizelInterceptor()` called in `addInterceptors()` will not do proxy.

Comment: whats the problem ? Any exception ?

Comment: i want to konw how does spring implement the annotation `@bean`

Comment: That's a very complicated answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Bean is a method level annotation which simply provides the bean configuration to the Spring container and the container uses it to inject the respective dependency. In short,it is just alternative to defining the bean using xml `<bean/>` tags.

I generally use @Bean while writing the simple unit tests, to provide the bean definitions in the same Test class file (rather than defining a separate xml for bean configurations).

I recommend you to go through the below link for more details:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html